# Clip raster with shapefile won't work without reprojection (Linux)

Tags: gdal, linux, centos, gdal-rasterize

So as the title suggests, I am trying to clip an image (UTM) using the OSM land polygon shapefile (WGS 84).

I use gdal_rasterize to do that and when I do it on a windows machine it works flawlessly regardless of the fact that they don't share the same SRS. When I try to do that on Linux I get an error saying that on-the-fly reprojection is not supported and the image is not clipped. This can be solved by reprojecting either of the files, but I can't reproject the image because it will change its dimensions (and I don't want that) and I also can't reproject the shapefile because there are a lot of errors which lead to an empty file.

I really can't find anything on the internet mentioning this issue.

PS. I use CentOS and Windows 10. GDAL in both machines is the newest version.
EDIT: I used the following command to clip the raster with the shapefile:

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 0 shapefile.shp raster.tif
```

Comment: Please add the command that you have used. I do not understand how you can clip with a shapefile by using gdal_rasterize.

Comment: I added the command I used.

Comment: That's not clipping, its rasterizing or burning. Please edit your question and then check your exact gdal version with `gdalinfo --version`. The manual https://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html says `Note that on the fly reprojection of vector data to the coordinate system of the raster data is only supported since GDAL 2.1.0.`.

Comment: Sorry, poor choice of words. It should be supported because I run GDAL 2.2.4. That's what makes no sense.

Comment: Add the versions you have on both machines to the body of your question. Certainly it makes no sense with version 2.2.4. Add "--debug on" into your command and hope that it gives some more information. Perhaps problem with projection libraries.

Comment: Have you found any differences in your GDAL installations? Version 2.2.4 should be high enough even it is not the newest as you wrote. The latest publishe version at the moment is 2.4.0.